# Error occurs when building .apk file with ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework

building the Android app produces the following error

> Error: Source path does not exist:
>   resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png
>
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit
>   code 1).

Answer (score 0):

What is your cordova and ionic-cli versions?

> you can try

```
npm i -g ionic@latest
//or
ionic cordova resources -f //should recreate the necessary resources.
```

> ```
> and you are edit your config.xml files.
> ```
>
> so you can try `ionic cordova platform add android`

Again, what is your cordova and ionic-cli versions?

Comment: cordova version -7.1.0

Comment: ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0

Comment: Try this, add in your config.xml `<platform name="android"/>
<platform name="ios"/>`